# Resetting reCaptcha by LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, recaptcha

I have a main component that contains reCaptcha as a child component, I'm trying to reset the reCaptcha from the main component if the user has entered the username and password wrong:

Main component code

```
 SignIn({
        username: this.UserName1,
        password: this.Password,
        recaptchaResponse : this.captchaResponse
        })
        .then((data) => {
      

            if(result != "Invalid Verification"){
                window.open(data,'_self');  
            }else{
          
                this.template.querySelector("c-google-captcha").refresh(); 
            }
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          
            this.Error = 'Invalid username';   
          
            
        })
 if(result != "Invalid Verification"){
                window.open(data,'_self');  
            }else{
              alert("1")
                this.template.querySelector("c-custom-google-captcha").refresh(); 
            }
```

Child component:

```
@api refresh(){
        document.addEventListener('grecaptchaReset',(e) => {
          
            grecaptcha.reset();
        }); 
       
    }
```

but that not working, so how could I reset the Recaptcha from the LWC component.

I'm trying to implement [this example](https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Implementing-reCAPTCHA-in-Community-Cloud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the code:

```
document.addEventListener('grecaptchaRender', function(e) {   
        onloadCallback = function() {
            grecaptchaReady = true;
            grecaptcha.render(e.detail.element, {
                'sitekey': 'reCAPTCHA_site_key',
                'callback': verifyCallback,
                'error-callback': errorCallback,
                'size': 'invisible',
                'badge': e.detail.hasOwnProperty('badge') ? e.detail.badge : 'bottomright'
            });
        };
        if (grecaptchaReady) {
            onloadCallback();
        }
    });
```

There is a event listender where the actual refresh happens. In the LWC you are actually adding the listener to this event "grecaptchaReset" on the refresh function. Instead I will suggest you to fire the custom event "grecaptchaReset" via the following code: this should do the job if you have added the head markup.

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('grecaptchaReset'));
```

This will do if there is an already loaded Recaptcha on the window

Comment: actually, I'm lost, where am I supposed to add the addEventListener code, and where do I have to add this.dispatchEvent code?

Comment: and document is causes an issue, the code not working after it

Comment: You have to add the addEventListner code in the header... 
The dispatchEvent code should be added where you need to reset the captcha.

Comment: anyone who want to add code to the header you have to go to your portal Builder then on the left sidebar setting icon==> advanced ===>edit Head Markup ==> add the above JS